# How to use indexing to make database access faster in web applications?

Tags: java, mysql, database

In a **web based java application**, I have a table with this schema

```
 Column          Datatype

 Userid          char(25) primary key;
 name            char(100)
 address         varchar(120)
 email           char(50) UNIQUE;
```

with **120000** records. (Cardinality)

**Now, I want to fetch the matching names (character by character) stored under column -> name.** when I start typing in a search box (through ajax obviously).

**e.g. if I write p then all names starting from letter p will be retrieved and would come in the list to populate.**

Right now I am not using any indexing
. So how could I use it to make the **access/search faster**.

The **database** I am using is **MySql 5** and **java as frontend**.

***Any suggestion for using appropriate collection for this purpose or any hashing would help in the database if yes please elaborate.***

> Though I have got the right track for this StackOverflowers. If I
>   modify the question and use hashing in place of indexing with all its
>   definition and usage statistics then how to do that and is it
>   beneficial?

Comment: Can you show the query you're using to select these records ?

Comment: That's a very simple one. `select name from Users where name like ` and then in my programming logic I fetch the character entered by user and get a check on it from the db and fire the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is just:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD INDEX(`name`);
```

And also, as names are variable length, use VARCHAR instead. For your key, use INT!

You can shrink your index to one byte if you search by one character only:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_table` ADD INDEX `name`(`name`(1));
```

Then, for better performance, you can use covering index. It means you need to have all required data indexed properly so it resides in memory (make sure you configured your server properly) and MySQL does not need to read from disk.

Comment: is it a necessity to use int for the key. How does it benefit ?

Comment: INT can be autoincrement value. INT is faster.

Comment: I liked on more solution to this post, that I don't use query for this purpose rather I fetch the data in a list and that list is then applied with binary search algorithm. What if I want to use hashing in this case how would it benefit the search.

Comment: For such small number of rows, you don't need that IMO.

Comment: Rows would increase in number! IMO means??

Comment: In my opinion. MySQL can handle millions of rows - no problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` properties are indexed in the table. So, your `email` and `userid` are already indexed. (**NOTE:** I seriously suggest you not to use `CHAR` for *userid*)

And use

```
INDEX `<any-name-here>` (`name`) # The `name` is the column and `<any-
                                 # name-here>` is the name of index.
```

Comment: Do I change the schema? What is the problem if I use fixed sized char sequence. But UserId is the one that a user enters by himself and it has to be character sequence. Any other alternative. Or do I hash the userId and then save it into db.

Comment: **I liked on more solution to this post, that I don't use query for this purpose rather I fetch the data in a list and that list is then applied with binary search algorithm. What if I want to use hashing in this case how would it benefit the search.**

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX id_index ON employee_table (employeeID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the indexing on the columns you will have in WHERE clause.

If your query will be most likely on name, create indexing on name column.

Remember this will leverage your insert/update record to that table which means your INSERT/UPDATE operations will be executed slower.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use DB queries. You could preload the (unique) names in a String array and perform a binary search for the characters typed  so far. This ensures maximum responisveness.

Comment: You mean to say I use the query `select name from users;` and with this a list would be returned and that gets saved into an ArrayList. Then binary search is applied over this ArrayList itself?

Comment: @pKs Yes, since you asked for Collectins but a HashMap wouldn' work for  substrings. The only drawback is that you need to update the array when new users will be inserted or deleted.

Comment: Would a `hashtable` do in this context? How much faster rate would I achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In generell you have to understand how a database index works.

But for your problems, some suggestions:

If you are using something like this (sorry, I don't know the MySql wildcard character, assuming it is %)

```
select * from MyTable where name like '%a%'
```

where a is a letter the user entered - this will never work on bigger tables, because the first % says that there are any characters before a - this means the whole table has to be scanned (this means the index is nearly useless).

Consider implementing the Autocompleter so that it starts autocompleting after at least 3 characters, which would lead to SQL similar to this:

```
select * from MyTable where name like 'abc%'
```

This would allow the database to use the index, because it only has use the data beginning with "abc"

Unfortunately you do not have an index at all on the column which can be used for your query, so you can add it via the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE 'table' ADD INDEX('column_you_search')
```

Hope this helps.